# Tradingview_ta Interval Changing on Indicators

Tags: python, tradingview-api

I'm using the Python library called tradingview_ta. I believe that the default length used for indicators is the last 21 closes. Is there a way to change this to make the amount of closes counted was a different number?

For example, I get the RSI eventually by doing:

```
ticker_info["ticker_rsi"] = val.get_analysis().indicators['RSI']
```

I believe that it's pulling 21 of the last closes to calculate the RSI. Is anyone aware of a way to change this to something like 14?

Thanks and have a good day.

Comment: did you find any solution?